# Hibernate duplicate primary key on restart using GenerationType.TABLE

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, orm

We're running into an issue where we have Event subclasses that use GenerationType.TABLE to generate the primary key, and when we restart the servers we are getting duplicate primary key errors.

We're using SQL Server and Hibernate version 3.5.1-Final.

Here's what our Hibernate annotations look like:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long eventID;
```

we don't specify the allocationSize so we're using the default value. The hibernate sequences table does increment but it seems like on restarts it's reusing already used ID's.

Comment: I am also running into similar issue. May I know what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try GenerationType.AUTO or SEQUENCE.
AUTO may work via hibernate magic, but SEQUENCE should create, funnily enough, a sequence in the database which it will use to get unique IDs.
Which SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You cannot use GenerationType.AUTO with InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_SUBCLASS. Google "Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for"